# Schedule an event using AlarmManager with ELAPSED_REALTIME

Tags: android

I have a question on scheduling an event using AlarmManager with ELAPSED_REALTIME.
I want to schedule an intent after 30 minutes except sleeping time. Which of the following code I should use?

Code 1:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                    30000, myIntent);
```

Code 2:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 30000, myIntent);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 30 * 60 * 1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, neither. "after 30 minutes except sleeping time" isn't supported. `elapsedRealtime()` counts sleeping time.

Ignoring that, you would want "Code 2".